# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to update my model calling Update from my controller but I'm getting the error:

```cs
The instance of entity type 'SearchFilter' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{SearchFilterId: -1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

I even tried calling the 2nd Update method at the end and all the things that are commented out, but didn't work. These are my update functions and also the mapping done with the Search children SearchSources and SearchFilters (convert from DTO model to entity)

```
public async Task Update(SearchInput search)
{          
      var entry = _context.Searches              
                .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == search.Name);     

      if (entry != null)
      {
            entry.Name = search.Name;
            entry.CreatedByUserId = search.CreatedByUserId;
            entry.ProjectId = search.ProjectId;
            entry.GlobalSearchText = search.GlobalSearchText;
            entry.SearchSources = new List<SearchSource>();
            entry.SearchFilters = new List<SearchFilter>();
            entry.SearchSources = search.SearchSources.Select(y => ManualMapper.ConvertSearchSourceDTOToSearchSourceEntity(y)).ToList();
            entry.SearchFilters = search.SearchFilters.Select(s => ManualMapper.ConvertSearchFilterDTOEntityToSearchFilterEntity(s)).ToList();

            //Update(entry);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                                                           
        }
}

public void Update(Search entity)
{
     var model = _context.Entry(entity);
     model.State = EntityState.Modified;
     _context.SaveChanges();
}

public static Entities.SearchSource? ConvertSearchSourceDTOToSearchSourceEntity(DTO.SearchSourceDTO? entity)
{
     return entity == null ? null : new Entities.SearchSource
     {
            DataSourceId = entity.DataSourceId,
            Name = entity.Name,
            SearchId = entity.SearchId,
            ShowActive = entity.ShowActive
      };
}

public static Entities.SearchFilter? ConvertSearchFilterDTOEntityToSearchFilterEntity(DTO.SearchFilterDTO entity)
{
      return entity == null ? null : new Entities.SearchFilter
      {
             SearchId = entity.SearchId,
             SearchFilterId = entity.SearchFilterId,
             GroupNum = entity.GroupNum,
             Logic = entity.Logic,
             OperatorId = entity.OperatorId,
             Value = entity.Value,
             VariableId = entity.VariableId,
             CategoryId = entity.CategoryId,
             CategoryTypeId = entity.CategoryTypeId,
             Order = entity.Order
       };
}
```

Comment: So what exact version of your code is not working? And where exactly exception is thrown?

Comment: I am not sure what is your primary key for your table, but it looks like you wanna add an entity with the same existing key ID. The safest way is to load from DB that entity, apply changes and save it back in DB.

Comment: @DA problem is with context already tracking and item when OP tries to attach entry with the same PK.

Comment: Please don't post swathes of commented out code; delete it or if it's demonstrating the problem reinstate it. We want the minimum code to represent your problem, not all the cruft from the past 3 hours failed attempts at resolving it

Comment: Exception is thrown after SaveChangesAsync. I cleaned the code. Version is .NET 6 EF Core.

Comment: I'm loading the entity with "entry" variable, modifying then saving, isn't that correct?

Comment: I was sendind SearchId -1 from the frontend. I updated it to the current search id and now it's all working fine, thanks